# Reading text files and calculate the mean length of every 3rd word

Tags: python-3.x

How to open a text file (includes 5 lines) and writting a program to calculate the mean length of the third word in line over all lines in this text file. (A word is defined as a group of characters surrounded by spaces and/or a line ending.)

Comment: Please demonstrate some of the approaches you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading this [Reading and writing Files in Python](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python) .. since what you are asking is a pretty basic question and I believe there are many resources out there. Just search :]

But not to leave you empty handed...

```
# mean_word.py

with open('file.txt') as data_file:
    # Split data into lists representing lines
    word_lists = [line.split(' ') for line in data_file.readlines()]

    word_count = sum(len(line) for line in word_lists)
    n_of_words = sum(len(word) for line in word_lists for word in line)
    mean_word_len = n_of_words / word_count
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm aware of the basic codes but my problem is to ONLY measure the length of the 3rd word per line

Comment: Well, I provided the basic code. You can modify this to take whatever word you want as simply as `reduced_word_lists = [line[::3] for line in word_lists]` and use that instead of word_lists.. this will take every third word. Or just `line[2] for the third word` (considering every line has at least 3 words)